# Why doesn't sticky footer work?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I have tried several things but my sticky header does not work. I've been trying several tutorials I found, but none worked. I have also looked at different post on stackoverflow but none described my problem.
Here's my HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='header>blabla</div>
    <div id='actualpage'>bblablabal</div>
    <div id='footer'>blablafooterblabla</div>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}
#container{
background-color:white;
width:100%;
min-height: 100%;
height:100%;
}
#actualpage{
width:750px; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#footer{
margin-top:-20px;
clear:both;
height:20px;
background-color:#A6CE39;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
min-width:100%;
bottom:0;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it header or footer?

Comment: Also maybe a fiddle would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `position: fixed` or `position:absolute` (if you don't want the footer stick to bottom while scrolling) to your `#footer`:

```
#footer{
    margin-top:-20px;
    clear:both;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#A6CE39;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    min-width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: position:fixed will stick to the bottom while scrolling

Comment: I'm not sure whether OP want this or not.

Comment: That works, but what if my pages are longer and I need to scroll? (The footer stays in the same place) And I don't want it to be fixed so it scrolls down with me, I just want it to be at the bottom of the page

Comment: Then remove `bottom: 0` from your `#footer`

Answer (score 1):

add     `position:absolute;` to your #footer
and `<div id='header>` should be `<div id='header'>`

Comment: That works, but what if my pages are longer and I need to scroll? (The footer stays in the same place) And I don't want it to be fixed so it scrolls down with me, I just want it to be at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to your `footer`, you may add `position: absolute` to your `#footer`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63Csm/1/)

```
#footer {
    margin-top:-20px;
    clear:both;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#A6CE39;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    min-width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: That works, but what if my pages are longer and I need to scroll? (The footer stays in the same place) And I don't want it to be fixed so it scrolls down with me, I just want it to be at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container{
background-color: yellow;
width:100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
#actualpage{
width:750px; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#footer{
margin-top:-32px;
clear:both;
height:20px;
background-color:#A6CE39;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
min-width:100%;
}


<div id='container'>
    <div id='header'>blabla</div>
    <div id='actualpage'>bblablabal</div>
</div>
    <div id='footer'>blablafooterblabla</div>
```

You need the footer outside of the container div.
Also, the bottom: 0; attribute was unnecessary and the negative margin for the footer needed to include the padding, which adds to the computed height

** also, add the closing "'" to id='header

Comment: refer to this link if you need more details: [http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

See working CodePen: http://cdpn.io/KwzuA

or use Flexbox - see demo: http://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/PwYQOJ/right/?editors=010

**Explanation**

Using `position` for a sticky footer is typically **not** a good idea, as it removes the element from the document flow and can have undesired results of the footer overlapping the content when scrolling.

A tried and trusted method is to add a "push" div inside the wrapper div and then have the footer div below, outside the wrapper. Like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>

  <div id="body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div><!--#body-->

  <div class="push"></div>

</div><!--#wrapper-->

<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

For the CSS, you will need to set `html`, `body` and `#wrapper` with `height: 100%`. You then set a fixed height to your `footer` and apply the same height to `#push`. Then you offset the body with a negative `margin-bottom`. The `#wrapper` needs a few other properties, like so:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -160px;  
}
.push, footer {
  height: 160px;
}
footer {
  /* remember the box model: padding+height  */
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 145px;
}
```

The footer will now flow properly when the content of the page extends below the fold, and will be sticky when the content does not.

** Use Flexbox **

The modern approach to this is using Flexbox. See: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

I used the Flexbox technique on a [recent project](http://www.metcash.com)